# Does there exist coprime numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^n+b$ is composite for every $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The title is the question, I will add here just the definition of coprimality and here it is:

We say that two numbers $a$ and $b$ are coprime ($a$ and $b$ are here natural numbers) if they do not have any common prime factor(other than $1$ for those who like to include $1$ in the set of prime numbers).

**Edit**: Thanks to lulu who reminded me about triviality when both $a$ and $b$ are odd, so let us add the condition that one of them is odd and one of them is even to make the question more interesting.

Comment: If $a,b$ are both odd then $a^n+b$ is even.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, I was excited so I forgot about such trivialities so I will edit to make it interesting.

Comment: @AntePaladin I believe the answer is known to be 'yes' even for a few examples where you can't find a single $k$ such that it's always divisible by $k$ (as would be the case, e.g., with $4^n+5$); I don't know of any example that doesn't fall to a handful of distinct modularity case analyses, though.

Comment: The edit does not avoid trivialities.  You could still have $a\equiv 1 (3)$ and $b=2$.  Then $a^n+b$ is always divisible by $3$.

Comment: As @StevenStadnicki suggests, an interesting variant of your question is to require that there be no single common factor of all the $a^n+b$.  I don't immediately see how to make an example like that...

Comment: @lulu I would like that you answer this question and add some (or one) cases which are not avoided by the requirement that one of them be even and one of them odd.

Comment: I just spent several minutes typing in a comment on your question on MO, only to find you had deleted it. That's the last you'll be hearing from me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Type it here, I wanted to hear your opinion but deleted it because of those who voted to close it, so that they do not have problem with it. I totally believe that when you say something like "That's the last you'll be hearing from me. " that it does not feel good. Where is friendly spirit? And the question is still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$14^n+19$ is divisible by $3$ when $n$ is odd and divisible by $5$ when $n$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

As requested, here is an elaboration on the comments.

It is relatively easy to find examples in which all the $a^n+b$ share a common factor.  for example, if $p$ is any prime take $$a\equiv 1\;b\equiv -1 \mod (p)$$

Then $a^n\equiv 1\;\forall n$ so $p|a^n+b$.  An explicit example would be:  $3\vert(7^n+2)\;\forall n$

Variant:  can we produce a sequence $s_n=a^n+b$ in which all terms are composite but there is no single prime which divides all the $s_n$? I note that another posted solution, from @user236182, gives an example.  Still, that example feels quite similar...can we avoid simple congruence types?

Update:  there are algebraic factorings, eg $$4^n-1=2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$$  of course, here, $b=-1$ is not a natural number.

Comment: It seems to me that a great insight is needed if we want to characterize the pairs $(a,b)$ which give only the composite numbers, the pairs $(a,b)$ which give only finitely many primes and pairs $(a,b)$ which give infinitely many prime numbers, if this comment is a version of the picture you had in mind?

Comment: Well, there are also examples like $4^n-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$ though here $b=-1$ is not a natural number.

Comment: Only if we go into the domain of integers but I like to restrict this problem to natural numbers.

Comment: A related notion is the Aurifeuillean factorizations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization