# Prove that a set of numbers can never consist of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

I noticed that for any integer $n>0$, $14^n+11$ would not be prime for up to $n=4$. Does this hold for all $n$? Is there a way to prove this or is this something that only works for some $n$?

Comment: For $n$ odd it's always divisible by 5 (because $14^n+11\equiv (-1)^n+1\equiv 0\pmod 5$) and for $n$ even it's always divisible by 3 (because $14^n+11\equiv (-1)^n+2\equiv 0\pmod 3$).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - how nice: would that one could (+1)...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Wow, what elegance.

Comment: I can't take too much credit; this is a small variant on an answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518015/does-there-exist-coprime-numbers-a-and-b-such-that-anb-is-composite-for#comment3092031_1518015 .