# On patterns of divisibility of the sequences of the from $a^n+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let us say that the sequence $a_n$ is partitioned by the subsequences $a_{i_1},a_{i_2},...a_{i_m}$ if for every $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ there is $i_j \in \{i_1,i_2,...,i_m\}$ such that $a(n_0)=a_{i_j}(n_0)$ and for every pair $(i_j,i_k)$ such that $i_j,i_k \in \{i_1,i_2,...,i_m\}$ and $i_j \neq i_k$ we have $a_{i_j}(n) \neq a_{i_k}(n)$, for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

The question is:

> Is it true that for every $n$-tuple $(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)$ such that $k_i \in \mathbb N$ ; $i=1,2,...,n$ there exist coprime natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that the sequence $s(m)=a^m+b$ can be partitioned into $n$ subsequences $s_1(m),s_2(m),...s_n(m)$ such that $k_i \mid s_i(m)$; $i=1,2,...,n$?

I somehow believe that this is not the case although I might be wrong, if there are some results in this direction or if this is some known fact I would appreciate your response about this problem I created.

The problem is to me interesting because if this is not true then we would have that sequences of the form $a^n+b$ (with $a$ and $b$ coprime) can satisfy only certain divisibility criteria (and not all), and that would be something that is interesting in itself and of itself.

Comment: This seems closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518418/prove-that-a-set-of-numbers-can-never-consist-of-prime-numbers (indeed, seems like a fancy way to generalize the very brief solution given to that problem), but maybe I'm mis-reading.

Comment: @JohnHughes There is some concrete similarity but this question of mine asks for some sort of broader generality in a sense that it could be the case that there will always be sequences of the form $a^n+b$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime which fit into some divisibility classes, to say it that way.

Comment: OK. I can't make sense of what you wrote (it's too early in the morning), but in the first sentence, your first equality refers to $a(n_0)$, which seems to be undefined. Or are you conflating subscript and functional notation for sequences, so that $a(n)$ refers to the $n$th item in the sequence $a$, which also, in the 6th word of the first sentence, seems to be denoted by $a_n$?

Comment: Also, should the last inequality of that sentence be $a_{i_j) (n) \ne a_{i_k} (m)$ for every $n, m$? Or do you really care that, say, the 4th terms of any pair of subsequences differ, but it's OK for the 4th term of one to be the 11th term of another? If it's the latter, then "partitioning" seems like a bad term for what you're describing.

Comment: @JohnHughes I write $a(n_0)$ for $a_{n_0}$ and if I did it right, I defined the partition in such a way that every term of the sequence $a_n$ is some term of some subsequence $a_{i_j}$ and every two subsequences $a_{i_j}$ and $a_{i_k}$ can have the same values $a_{i_j}(n_0)=a_{i_k}(n_1)$  if  for example $n_0 \neq n_1$, but can not have the same values if $n_0=n_1$.

Comment: Following what you said, this maybe is not in the spirit of the true partitioning where true disjointness would be defined as you did, so that $a_{i_j}(m) \neq a_{i_k}(n)$, for every $n$ and $m$ and $i_j \neq i_k$, but I do not assert that. And what kind of term would you use instead of partition?

Comment: I guess I'd say "collection of (possibly overlapping) subsequences" for that, but it's up to you, of course.