# Four types of behavior of the sequences of the form $a^n+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are coprime natural numbers.

I would like to have at least one example of $a$ and $b$ for each of the following statements:

> 1) $s(n)=a^n+b$ is composite for every $n \in \mathbb N$.
>
> 2) $s(n)=a^n+b$ is composite for some $n_1,n_2,...n_k$ and prime for $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{n_1,n_2,...,n_k\}$.
>
> 3) $s(n)=a^n+b$ is prime for some $n_1,n_2,...n_k$ and composite for $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{n_1,n_2,...,n_k\}$.
>
> 4) $s(n)=a^n+b$ is prime for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Do you take $0\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: @Wojowu No. :))

Comment: You've asked the $1)$ question before ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518015/does-there-exist-coprime-numbers-a-and-b-such-that-anb-is-composite-for)).

Comment: @user236182 Yes I know. Now it is just one of the four possible cases (if all four are possible)?

Comment: This is one of 4 questions the user has posted here about $a^n+b$. See the user page.

Answer (score 2):

1) $a=1,b=3$. $a^n+b=4$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

2) is impossible. Since $a^n+b$ need to be non-constant, we get $a>1$. Let $p$ be any prime dividing $a^1+b$. Then for any $k\in\Bbb N$, $a^{p^k}+b\equiv a+b\equiv 0\pmod p$ using Fermat's little theorem, and $a^{p^k}+b>a+b\geq p$, so $a^n+b$ is composite for infinitely many $p$.

4) $a=1,b=1$. $a^n+b=2$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

I couldn't find an example for 3), but well-known conjecture states that $a=2,b=1$ satisfies this (i.e. that there are only finitely many Fermat primes).

Comment: Is there any known example of 4) if $a,b>1$?

Comment: Just to avoid trivial trivialities.

Comment: Oh, so the proof of 2) eliminates 4). I did not see it till now.

Comment: Yes, that's true. As for nontrivial example for 1), we can take $a=3,b=1$. Then all numbers will be even.